# Remove word from dictionary

Tags: spell-checking

I'm using `gvim`:

```
$ gvim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Feb 16 2017 06:36:51)
MacOS X (unix) version
Included patches: 1-329
Compiled by Homebrew
```

I was editing the following line of text:

```
enable mouse scrolling, pane selection, pan reiszing and so on.
```

I noticed "reiszing" was misspelled so I used the following command to turn on spellcheck:

```
setlocal spell spelllang=en_us
```

"reiszing" was highlighted as expected but then I accidently used the [`zg`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/spell.html#zg) command which added the word to my dictionary. I grepped through `/usr/share/dict/words` but didn't find "reiszing".

- How do I remove this word from my dictionary?
- If the word isn't stored in `/usr/share/dict/words`, then where is it?

I read in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9239277/2909897) that the command

```
set runtimepath?
```

Can be used to find the paths that `vim` uses:

```
~/.vim
/usr/local/Cellar/macvim/8.0-127/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/vimfiles
/usr/local/Cellar/macvim/8.0-127/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime
/usr/local/Cellar/macvim/8.0-127
/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/vimfiles/after
~/.vim/after
```

I was able to fix my problem by blowing away the files:

```
$ rm /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/8.0-127/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/spell/en.utf-8.add
$ rm /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/8.0-127/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/spell/en.utf-8.add.spl
```

This worked fine for me now becuase it was the first time this happened but I'm curious if there is a simpler and less destructive way to remove a word from the dictionary after adding it with the `zg` command.

I've tried `cmd + f`ing the [spell man page](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/spell.html) for "remove word" but found nothing.

Comment: sorry for the typo! please see edit

Comment: Do you mean zg (instead of ng) ?   :-)

Answer (score 32):

To remove a word, try `zuw` and/or `zug`

```
I've tried cmd + fing the spell man page for "remove word" but found nothing.
```

For a `cmd+f` search, I have had more success searching only on "remove" :-)

If you turn on spelling with `setlocal spell spelllang=en_us` then your long term dictionary is in your home directory.  Mine is at:

```
 ~/.vim/spell/en.utf-8.add
```

This is where `zg` adds words.

While you can edit `~/.vim/spell/en.utf-8.add` in vim under a different tab to remove erroneous entries, the `zug` command is probably easier.  :-)

The `zG` command adds to a temporary file, under `/tmp`

`help spellfile` (`help spf`) can provide more details about the file's location and format.

Comment: thank you for the response StandardEyre, I updated my question, the file you mentioned doesn't exist